# Is there any way to make two horizontal pager of accompanist library to work synchronously?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

What I am trying to achieve is if there are two horizontal pagers, then on swiping top one to left then the bottom horizontal pager should swipe to right and vice-versa, have tried using pagerState scrollBy method but not getting desired output

Comment: Please share  your code where you have tried with `scrollBy` method.

Comment: I calculated the current Page Item Offset and on the basis of if I scrolled progrmatically but wasnt getting desire output, currenlty dont have the code and implemented how normal pagerWorks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, you need to determine which pager is scrolled and which one should follow it. This can be done with `isScrollInProgress`, I use it inside `derivedStateOf` to avoid unnecessary re-compositions.

Then I run `LaunchedEffect`. I'm passing pair of pager states in needed order, or null, as a `key`, so `LaunchedEffect` will be re-launched when scrolling stops/starts. Using `snapshotFlow`, it is possible to track changes in the result of a block whose calculations depend on state changes.

`PagerState` has scroll position information in the properties `currentPage` and `currentPageOffset`. `scrollToPage` takes only `0..1` values for page offset, but `currentPageOffset` can be less than zero when scrolling backward.

Suppose `currentPage = 2` and `currentPageOffset = -0.1`. In this case, I will get `1.9` in `pagePart`, and I need to split it back to get `1` and `0.9`. To do this I use `divideAndRemainder`: it will return a list of the form `listOf(1.0, 0.9)`.

```kotlin
Column {
    val count = 10
    val firstPagerState = rememberPagerState()
    val secondPagerState = rememberPagerState()

    val scrollingFollowingPair by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            if (firstPagerState.isScrollInProgress) {
                firstPagerState to secondPagerState
            } else if (secondPagerState.isScrollInProgress) {
                secondPagerState to firstPagerState
            } else null
        }
    }
    LaunchedEffect(scrollingFollowingPair) {
        val (scrollingState, followingState) = scrollingFollowingPair ?: return@LaunchedEffect
        snapshotFlow { scrollingState.currentPage + scrollingState.currentPageOffset }
            .collect { pagePart ->
                val divideAndRemainder = BigDecimal.valueOf(pagePart.toDouble())
                    .divideAndRemainder(BigDecimal.ONE)

                followingState.scrollToPage(
                    divideAndRemainder[0].toInt(),
                    divideAndRemainder[1].toFloat(),
                )
            }
    }

    HorizontalPager(
        count = count,
        state = firstPagerState,
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
    ) {
        Text(it.toString())
    }
    HorizontalPager(
        count = count,
        state = secondPagerState,
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
    ) {
        Text(it.toString())
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: can you give a little explaination of your logic inside launchedEffect

Comment: @sarthakgupta I've updated my answer with explanations